# NoSuchMethodError : the getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building app with Flutter which's still new to me, and I'm stuck at those exception in that title.

The problem is when I tried to call "providedService.docs.length" at ListView.builder, it would return those exception if it's null and no exception when there's a data.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the get Length function should return null or 0 value so that the ListView would display nothing when there's no data.

```
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: providedService.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text('${(index + 1)}'),
              ),
              title: Text(
                providedService.docs[index],
              ),
            ),
            Divider()
          ],

        ),

      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: providedService?.docs?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text('${(index + 1)}'),
              ),
              title: Text(
                providedService.docs[index],
              ),
            ),
            Divider()
          ],

        ),

      ),
    );
```

Use this, if the object is null it will return 0, so the listview will show the empty list

Comment: Its always a pleasure to help and please have a look at this
https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet :)